# ETCD key names - what characters are supported?

Tags: key, etcd, etcd3

Can't find this in the docs.

Exactly what characters are supported by ETCD in key names and values?
Does it support every UTF-8 character? Are there any characters it handles in a special way?
Are there any forbidden characters?

According to docs, the name of the key must not be empty. But there seem to be little info about other restrictions..

Comment: When using java clients the key and value are a sequence of bytes. This makes me think that you can use any charset and symbols (or whatever that can be converted to a sequence of bytes).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the case.